# Heroku can't find Websocket library, even though the code works locally and deployed successfully on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, websocket, binance

I'm running into a weird error and not sure why...

I've this python app that uses **'websocket-client'** library to connect to binance wss stream.

The app works fine locally and I'm getting no error deploying on Heroku.

But when looking into the app log on heroku, I see that the app keeps crashing at...

```
2022-02-01T17:44:29.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2022-02-01T17:44:31.788428+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-02-01T17:44:34.189260+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python bot2.py`
2022-02-01T17:44:34.843902+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-02-01T17:44:35.061463+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-02-01T17:44:35.061481+00:00 app[worker.1]:   File "bot2.py", line 2, in <module>
2022-02-01T17:44:35.061484+00:00 app[worker.1]:     import websockets
2022-02-01T17:44:35.061487+00:00 app[worker.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'websockets'
2022-02-01T17:44:35.194532+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-02-01T17:44:35.252351+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

I've tried both '[websocket-client](https://websocket-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)' and '[websockets](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)' libraries and having the same issue...

Anyone has any idea why Heroku won't work with websocket libraries...?

Thanks!!

EDIT-1: I did declare them as dependencies. Here's my requirements.txt file:

```
numpy
TA-Lib
python-binance
websocket-client
websockets
```

Comment: "Anyone has any idea why Heroku won't work with websocket libraries...?"—did you declare them as dependencies? Please [edit] your question and show us your `requirements.txt` and / or `Pipfile` files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I did declare them as dependencies. Added my requirements.txt file in the question.

Comment: Is that file in the root directory of your project? Do you also have a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`?